# Series object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample pandas DataFrame:

```
id  product_type    qty
1   product_type 1  100
2   product_type 2  300
3   product_type 1  200
```

I want to delete `product_type` in the column `product_type` in order obtain the following new DataFrame:

```
id  product_type    qty
1   1               100
2   2               300
3   1               200
```

This is how I tried to do it:

```
orders['product_type'].strip('product_type ')
```

However there is an error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you need [`.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) in front of it as it's a [string accessor method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling):

```
orders['product_type'].str.strip('product_type ')



In [6]:
df['product_type'] = df['product_type'].str.strip('product_type ')
df

Out[6]:
   id product_type  qty
0   1            1  100
1   2            2  300
2   3            1  200
```

Or pass a regex to extract the numbers to [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [8]:
df['product_type'] = df['product_type'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')
df

Out[8]:
   id product_type  qty
0   1            1  100
1   2            2  300
2   3            1  200
```